# Web Speech API - Speech Synthesis has delay on chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

maybe some of you experienced the same:

When using [Speech Synthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis) via Javascript via:

```
const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
utterance.addEventListener('start', () => {
  console.log("Starting speak!");
});
window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
```

"Starting speak" is triggered like 1-4 seconds before voice is really speaking.
It's working fine on safari on macOS but not on firefox neither chrome.

Comment: Knowing apple that might have not been a coincidence, you know, it working fine on Safari, but magically causing issues on other browsers

Comment: I'm not seeing any delay in Chrome on Linux..   Do you keep the instance of `utterance` when speaking more words?.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in Chrome using the code supplied in the question. The only way I could create a lag was to modify the code to use something other than the default browser supplied voice. It seems there is a one time delay while Chrome loads the alternative voice.

Comment: The thin is: on Windows and linux the problem is not there for me neither. It just happens on mac: chrome/firefox. @KitangaNday do you have any reference to a bug for that maybe on mac?

Comment: No, I couldn't find any report of there being a delay when the API's start event is called. I know that Chrome uses Google Translate services for it's text to speech, maybe that's the reason for the lag, but that doesn't explain why Firefox would also be lagging. Btw, have you tried using `utterance.onstart = () => {}` instead?

Comment: @SebiB can you please add which Mac (intel/M1/M2) which MacOS and FF/Chrome versions?

Comment: Also: which language and voice did you use? I found that English system voice (Karen, Sandy etc.) don't have this issue while for example German voices (Anna, Markus) have this issue

Answer (score 1):

Some voices might be flawed.

This has a delay in FireFox 116.0.2 on Mac and causes CPU use to spike.

```
window.speechSynthesis.speak(Object.assign(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hallo Bob'), {
  voice: window.speechSynthesis.getVoices().find(v => v.lang === 'de-DE' && v.name == "Anna")
}))
```

Comment: Linux, (PopOS), Firefox -> 115.0 (64-bit),  apart from the first time, (loading delay, most likely).  It's then instant, CPU usage minimal.  3.5% on a rather old Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700, 8 year old CPU.   The OP was also on MaxOS, could this be Mac specific?   Could it be M1/M2 specific, maybe OK on Intel, so could be an issue with compatibility layer, and Firefox don't have this bit native Arm yet.  I wonder if there are any none Mac users having this delay?..